# What's the title of the manga in which the protagonist wears a magical mask to save his twin brother?

Tags: story-identification, manga, demons

About 3 or 4 years ago, I read a josei-fantasy manga which told the story of two rich twin brothers that inherited the top elite academy owned by their strict grandfather. One of them,  who is the protagonist, is blond-haired and tends to be rather cold and tsundere whereas the other one is dark-haired and is very friendly and carefree; not to mention that they have a white bunny and a black bunny that resemble each other-unfortunately, I can't recall their names but those 2 cute pets are quite similar to Cinnamon Roll from Sanrio.

As far as I can barely remember, those twin brothers were getting ready for the ceremony in which one of them would become the headmaster of the academy like their grandpa and the remaining one would be the legitimate owner of a mask possessed by a legendary demon that feasts on human darkness (treachery, deceit, pretending to be someone else, hiding one's true self behind a facade.) However, something went awfully wrong. Their granddad had decided to test his grandchildren by giving them something different to what they were eagerly expecting: the easygoing dark-haired boy became the headmaster of the academy and the responsible fair-haired child was given the demonic mask (needless to say that the protagonist had no idea that the so-called demon mask held unimaginable powers).. After such heartbreaking deception, the twins tried to comfort each other by bearing in mind that there must  have been a good reason why they finally had gotten what they didn't want. The following day, the protagonist learned that his beloved brother wasn't willing to accept their grandpa's decision and, in an attempt to get the mask back, invoked the legendary demon to make a deal but he was rejected by the demonic entity due to the fact that the protagonist was his new master. As a result of all this mess, the dark-haired child fell into a coma.

Comment: [He fell into a comma?](https://i.imgur.com/YFdVQ8V.png)

Comment: @Valorum  That is a terrible fate which hppens to fictional characters when the writer is careless.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Or indeed when you're [carless](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DUvJql2W4AELbo-.jpg)

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

This is *[Hakudatsu no Masquerade](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shirodatsu-no-masquerade)*.

> Elite Development Education Academy, Noblesse Oblige. The grandson of the academy's chairman, promised heir as the next chairman, Inaba Hakuto. The kind-hearted, younger brother who supports him, Inaba Kokuto. However, with the chairman's death, the fate of the twins begins to greatly warp. The one who holds the key is, the demon who resides in the mask... Masquerade...

The story has two twins as the protagonists; as mentioned in the question, they are light haired and dark haired with seemingly opposite personalities. They also have a pair of white and black bunnies, likely a reference to their last name, Inaba.

[image: The twins and their bunnies]

Their grandfather, the head of the academy they attend, dies shortly after the start of the story from a prolonged illness. The black haired twin becomes the head. It is not immediately shown that the light haired twin inherits anything, but shortly after he ends up in an unusual space and signs a contract with a demon that grants him a mask.

[image: The demon]

Found by searching mangaupdates for the tags `Mask/s` and `Twin/s`